# How to use Position Select in Matrix blocks?

Tags: position

How does one use position selects to float an element in Craft CMS template? Say I want to allow an author to center or float a quote block to the right or left using a position select. How would I do this in the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would typically just pop out a CSS class based on their selection.

So:

```
<blockquote class="align--{{ block.myAlignment }}"></blockquote>
```

Just pop the value out into your markup, and then write the CSS to produce whatever effect you need